# FATAL: [ssh-agent] Unable to start agent - Jenkins SCP

Tags: jenkins, ssh, scp, ssh-agent

I am trying to do SCP from linux remote server to the Jenkins workspace(Windows server) using SSH agent. I have cygwin terminal already installed

```
scp uname@host name:/home/vm/myfile  /cygwin/I/.jenkins/workspace/job.
```

I get the below error:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: [ssh-agent] Unable to start agent
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.createSSHAgentEnvironment(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:255)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.preCheckout(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:225)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.preCheckout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:76)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [ssh-agent] Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider.
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper$SSHAgentEnvironment.<init>(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:378)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshagent.SSHAgentBuildWrapper.createSSHAgentEnvironment(SSHAgentBuildWrapper.java:248)
    ... 7 more
```